# ASP NET mvc 2 Template for EditorFor and DisplayFor

Tags: .net, templates, asp.net-mvc-2, editorfor

I would like to control or customise the output generated by DisplayFor and EditorFor so it doesn't render the default html css tags for example:

 .......

I would like this to be for all views not just a type or system type? And what is the simplest solution?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't understand this statement "I would like this to be for all views not just a type or system type?" Please elaborate.

Comment: Sorry, for any view that needs to be rendered apply this template. I want total control of the html that is generated for each view regardless of the model/view model used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can always create a *custom* DisplayFor/EditorFor ***.asxc** file that resides in either `Shared/DisplayTemplates or -/EditorTemplates`, pass the relevant **type** to it and just render what *you want*.

Following article explains it in further details:

(This introduces the DisplayFor method - EditorFor works ***exactly*** the same way)

Comment: That's a good example and the kind of thing I am looking for but it is tied to a specific type i.e your model class. What would be nice if it was generic and could be used for all types? I think an Object.ascx is needed right?

Comment: You could try this. But I'm afraid how you're going about rendering specific things for specific models?

e.g. You're passing a Person to that Partial View - How would you know which fields to render and which not? 
I don't think you'd want to render `id` field if it's related to a database, right?

Comment: @FaizanS.: The link in your answer no longer works. Please consider removing it, or replacing it with a new link if you can find the article elsewhere